# Showing newest mysql rows in front end search

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone help me show the newest row ids when searching the database. Here is my code, limited to showing 100 results, but it shows the oldest rows first. I would like to show the newest rows. Keep in mind i do not have a time stamp.

```
$query_str = "SELECT * FROM puppy_data 
              WHERE (`breed` LIKE '%".$query."%') 
              OR (`sex` LIKE '%".$query."%') 
              LIMIT 100 " ;
```

Comment: `order by` (date\id)

Comment: So when there's no timestamp, how would you like to tell which row is newer?

Answer (score 2):

Try this (assuming you have a row called 'id').

```
$query_str = "SELECT * FROM puppy_data
              WHERE (breed LIKE '%".$query."%')
              OR (sex LIKE '%".$query."%')
              ORDER BY id SORT DESC LIMIT 100" ;
```

Comment: You should probably explain the sort and the descending flag, and provide a reference.

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the question as being Solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ORDER BY <column(s)> DESC` clause to sort by one or more columns in descending order.  This works if you have an auto incrementing ID column, or a DateTime created_at column.  Remember that ideally the column you are ordering by should be an indexed one.

```
SELECT * FROM puppy_data
WHERE (breed LIKE '%".$query."%')
OR (sex LIKE '%".$query."%')
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html